# Reading values in many to many relation

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables called `student` and `subject`. Two of them are connected in many to many relation called `student_subject` which contains `id_student` and `id_subject`. My goal is to print name of student, and name of subject based on the values in the table `student_subject`. I tried this:

```
$query="SELECT st.fname,su.name FROM student_subject AS ss,student as st,subject as su  WHERE ss.id_student=st.id_student and ss.id_subject=su.id_subject";

$exe=mysqli_query($con,$query);


while($res=mysqli_fetch_array($exe))
{
echo '<option value='.$res["st.fname"].'>'.$res["su.name"].'</option> <br/>';
}
```

This code works when i run it as as sql query in phpmyadmin. Result shows me name of student and corresponding subject. BUT when I try to print this with php, it shows me nothing...

Comment: results are returned as fname and name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need to name the tables when echoing the data. Try this:

```
echo '<option value='.$res["fname"].'>'.$res["name"].'</option> <br/>';
```

Comment: tnx a lot for fast help :)